# understanding mason filter component

Tags: regex, perl, mason

I am new to mason.
I would like to know what the following piece of code does :

```
<%filter>
   s/(\w+)/\U$1/g
</%filter>
```

I understand that a <%filter> block is called after a component has finished running. It is given the entire output of the component in the $_ variable, and any changes to this variable are reflected in the output of the component.

But what is the \U$1 mean here ?

Comment: I don't really know what the `\U` is but `$1` is a back reference meaning it points to the first group of parens. Essentially this is adding a `\U` before whatever word characters it finds

Answer (score 3):

`s/(\w+)/\U$1/g` means search for one or more word characters and if it's find any then it would be stored  into a group. In the replacement part, all the characters are replaced by captured characters, `\U` turns all the captured characters into Uppercase letters . `g` modifier means global.

Comment: Correct, it uppercases all the word characters.